React app with anchor 0.30.1 error: "WalletSendTransactionError: Unexpected error..."
I started getting this when I began using an anchor program using 0.30.1.
Nothing else changed in the client. I am trying to sign with a phantom wallet (has devnet SOL via React frontend). I have anchor 0.30.1 in the client deps.
EDIT: This is on devnet using Vite
The test in the program work fine, was able to successfully deploy to devnet.
This error is arising when trying to send a transaction via React sendTransaction.
It does not seem like Devnet is down. but maybe it is...?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is driving me nuts as the errors thrown are highly generic in the console.
Client code:
...
  const { connection } = useConnection();
  const anchorWallet = useAnchorWallet();
  const { sendTransaction } = useWallet();
...

// makeCreatePoolTxn
  const transaction = new Transaction();
  const ix = await program.methods
    .initializePool(args.token.symbol, args.token.name, '')
    .accounts({
      signer: creator,
      metadata: metadataPDA
    })
    .instruction();
  transaction.add(ix);
  const latestBlock = await args.connection.getLatestBlockhash();
  transaction.feePayer = creator;
  transaction.recentBlockhash = latestBlock.blockhash;
  return transaction;

...

const transaction = await makeCreatePoolTxn({
        connection,
        wallet: anchorWallet,
        token: tokenPayload,
      });
      const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection);


anchor context
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::associated_token::AssociatedToken;
use anchor_spl::{
    metadata::Metadata as Metaplex,
    token::{Mint, Token},
    token_interface::{TokenAccount},
};

use crate::bonding_curve::constants::DEFAULT_TOKEN_DECIMALS;
use crate::amm::constants::*;
use crate::state::pool::*;

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(symbol: String, name: String, uri: String)]
pub struct InitializePool<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [POOL_MINT_SEED.as_bytes(), symbol.as_bytes()],
        bump,
        payer = signer,
        mint::decimals = 9,
        mint::authority = mint,
    )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    /// CHECK: New Metaplex Account being created
    #[account(mut)]
    pub metadata: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [POOL_BONDING_SEED.as_bytes(), symbol.as_bytes()],
        bump,
        payer = signer,
        space = 8 + std::mem::size_of::<BondingPool>(),
    )]
    pub pool: Account<'info, BondingPool>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = signer,
        seeds = [POOL_AMM_SEED.as_bytes(), symbol.as_bytes()],
        bump,
        space = 8 + std::mem::size_of::<AMMPool>(),
    )]
    pub amm_pool: Account<'info, AMMPool>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = signer,
        associated_token::mint = mint,
        associated_token::authority = amm_pool,
    )]
    pub token_vault: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = signer,
        seeds = [POOL_SOL_VAULT_SEED.as_bytes(), symbol.as_bytes()],
        bump,
        space = 8 + std::mem::size_of::<PoolSolVault>(),
    )]
    pub sol_vault: Account<'info, PoolSolVault>,

    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub token_metadata_program: Program<'info, Metaplex>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
}


could you post the full error logs

They are very generic. Please see below. I will update post with screenshots of error(s), as well for clarity.
GOT ERROR Error: Unexpected error     at Pi.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:3:240911)     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)     at s (<anonymous>:1:1456)
and
WalletSendTransactionError: Unexpected error     at StandardWalletAdapter.sendTransaction (@solana_wallet-adapter-react.js?v=11ea88f1:2210:15)     at async @solana_wallet-adapter-react.js?v=11ea88f1:2810:12

this is indeed weird

I guess I’m going to roll back 30.0. may try and eliminate things from context to see if some oddities with how 30.1 is building the transaction for some of the resolved accounts. guess is solana versions are whack and does solana react package does not like how 30.1 does things.

I have deduced the issue down to this account being passed in context:
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [POOL_MINT_SEED.as_bytes(), symbol.as_bytes()],
        bump,
        payer = signer,
        mint::decimals = 9,
        mint::authority = mint,
    )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

For whatever reason, anchor 30.1 in the client does like this...will post more findings

Are you using chrome? Try switching browsers. I switched from chrome to brave and the errors stopped
